# How can Sass (SCSS) be used to concisely style multiple elements with unique colors and background images?

Tags: html, css, loops, sass

Can SCSS be used to consolidate this CSS, which assigns colors and images to multiple elements, and make it easier to edit as a developer?

```css
.tile--hamburger {
  color: tan;
  background-image: url("hamburger.jpg");
}

.tile--hotdog {
  color: red;
  background-image: url("hotdog.jpg");
}

.tile--fries {
  color: yellow;
  background-image: url("fries.jpg");
}

.tile--chicken {
  color: brown;
  background-image: url("chicken.jpg");
}

.tile--salad {
  color: green;
  background-image: url("salad.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@each` directive in Sass could be used to iterate over a map of variables to make this code much more manageable.

```css
$foods: (
  hamburger: tan,
  hotdog: red,
  fries: yellow,
  chicken: brown,
  salad: green
);

@each $name, $color in $foods {
  .tile--#{$name} {
    background-image: url('#{$name}.jpg');
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way - but any of these solutions are likely over-optimised. SCSS is much better used for organization than it is for functional things.

```
$color: tan;
$highlight: lightblue;

@mixin assign-things($background-color, $image-src) {
  color: $background-color;
  background-image: url($image-src);
}

.tile {
  // tile styles...

  &.hamburger { // specific tile styles...
    @include assign-things($color, 'hamburger.jpg');
  }
  &.hotdog {
    @include assign-things($highlight, 'hotdog.jpg');
  }
  // ...
}
```

This is the part I would recommend most...

```
.tile {
  // rules
  &.specific-tile {
    // rules
  }
}
```

or stylus

```
.tile
  // rules
  &.specific-tile
    // rules
```